# Как пишутся сложные парсеры на php?

Tags: php, парсер

Не является проблемой подменить заголовки, реферер, уникальный ип, куки.

Что является проблемой - отследить перечень перенаправлений, модификацию кук в процессе перенаправлений, особенно, если на сайте присутствует много js или не дай бог технологии посложнее/запросов десятки и в каждом необходимо разобраться

Через отладчик фаерфокса проверять передаваемые куки, необходимые хеадеры может быть слишком трудозатратно.

Какие есть средства, позволяющие проанализировать цепочку запросов до получения конечного результата, в идеале сами генерирующие код, либо сильно облегчающие генерацию кода на php? На ум приходят браузерные плагины, но я таких не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо вручную обрабатывать редиректы, для этого нужно выключить авторедиректы (например, в cURL за это отвечает опция `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, в других библиотеках - читайте документацию).

Запрос нужно осуществлять в цикле.
При получении ответа обрабатываете полученные заголовки. В конце итерации проверяете код ответа - если `301`, `302` (или другой, отвечающие за редирект) и имеется заголовок `location`, то извлекаете следующий URL из этого заголовка и повторяете итерацию цикла.